# gsutil multiprocessing and multithreaded does not sustain cpu usage & copy rate on GCP instance

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading, gsutil

I am running a script to copy millions (2.4 million to be exact) images from several gcs buckets into one central bucket, with all buckets in the same region. I was originally working from one csv file but broke it into 64 smaller ones so each process can iterate through its own file as to not wait for the others. When the script launches on a 64 vCPU, 240 GB memory instance on GCP it runs fine for about an hour and a half. In 75 minutes 155 thousand files copied over. The CPU usage was registering a sustained 99%. After this, the CPU usage drastically declines to 2% and the transfer rate falls significantly. I am really unsure why this. I am keeping track of files that fail by creating blank files in an errors directory. This way there is no write lock when writing to a central error file. Code is below. It is not a spacing or syntax error, some spacing got messed up when I copied into the post. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Zach

```
 import os
 import subprocess
 import csv
 from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool
 from multiprocessing import Pool as ProcessPool
 import multiprocessing

 gcs_destination = 'gs://dest-bucket/'
 source_1 = 'gs://source-1/'
 source_2 = 'gs://source-2/'
 source_3 = 'gs://source-3/'
 source_4 = 'gs://source-4/'

 def copy(img):
    try:
            imgID = img[0] # extract name
            imgLocation = pano[9] # extract its location on gcs
            print pano[0] + "   " + panoLocation
            source = ""
            if imgLocation == '1':
                    source = source_1 
            elif imgLocation == '2':
                    source = source-2 
            elif imgLocation == '3':
                    source = source_3 
            elif imgLocation == '4':
                    source = source_4 
            print str(os.getpid())
            command = "gsutil -o GSUtil:state_dir=.{} cp {}{}.tar.gz {}".format(os.getpid(), source, imgID , g
            prog = subprocess.call(command, shell="True")
            if prog != 0:
                    command = "touch errors/{}_{}".format(imgID, imgLocation)
                    os.system(command)
    except:
            print "Doing nothing with the error"

def split_into_threads(csv_file):
  with open(csv_file) as f:
            csv_f = csv.reader(f)
            pool = ThreadPool(15)
            pool.map(copy, csv_f)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    file_names = [None] * 64
    # Read in CSV file of all records
    for i in range(0,64):
            file_names[i] = 'split_origin/origin_{}.csv'.format(i)

    process_pool = ProcessPool(multiprocessing.cpu_count())
    process_pool.map(split_into_threads, file_names)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For gsutil, I agree strongly with the multithreading suggestion by adding -m. Further, composite uploads, -o, may be unnecessary and undesirable as the images are not GB each in size and need not be split into shards. They're likely in the X-XXMB range.

Within your python function, you are calling gsutil commands, which are in turn calling further python functions. It should be cleaner and more performant to leverage the google-made client library for python, available [below]. Gsutil is built for interactive CLI use rather than for calling programatically.
https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-python

Also, for gsutil, see your ~/.boto file and look at the multi-processing and multi-threading values. Beefier machines can handle greater thread and process. For reference, I work from my Macbook Pro w/ 1 process and 24 threads. I use an ethernet adapter and hardwire into my office connection and get incredible performance off internal SSD (>450 Mbps). That's Megabits, not bytes. The transfer rates are impressive, nonetheless

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend you to use the "-m" flag on gsutil to enable multi thread copy.

Also as an alternative you can use the Storage Transfer Service [1] to move data between buckets.

[1] https://cloud.google.com/storage/transfer/

Comment: This is a good alternative. Comments suggested by @Evan C also relevant. Thanks.